# java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.msg.SAXMessages, locale en_US

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat7

I'm receiving the following exception while trying to deploy my java app to tomcat7 using java7, hibernate, mysql.

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.msg.SAXMessages, locale en_US
```

I've spent a lot of time surfing around the web looking for an answer, but I have yet to come up with one. Does anybody know what this error means or how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you shed some light what is your application looks like?

if it is JSP - you may find answer here: [Can’t Find Bundle For Base Name Xxx, Locale En_US](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-xxx-locale-en_us/)

Comment: I'm using the Tapestry5 framework and oddly enough, this just recently became an issue. What is this missing jar?

Comment: Another strange issue is the fact it does not happen on my local tomcat server, this only appears to be an issue on our sandbox server. This worked last night on the sandbox without issue and now today it's an issue. The server team indicated no changers were made to the server. I'm just not sure how it manages to work locally but not on sandbox.

Comment: so it might be one of three cases:
1. missing jar

2. wrong locale

3. incorrect class-loaders order
try to setup test from here http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xerces-j-users/200105.mbox/%3C12785F32B502D511B347000412267AD16A3255@corpexc6.freightliner.com%3E

Comment: Is this a jar that is suppose to reside on Tomcat, or within my project?

Comment: It looks as if xercesImpl was missing. I've never had to use that before, I'm not sure why its now requiring it.

Comment: Accepted answer doesn't actually answers the question. Code Junkie's comment to it does.